# Google Play Game Services Achievements gone on iOS

Tags: ios, achievements, google-play-games

The Good: 
Achievements and Leaderboards work perfectly on Android
Leaderboards work on iOS

The Bad:
Achievements don't work on iOS

Everything works flawlessly on android.
Now running my game on iOS however will unlock achievements (banner shows up) but after a user logout and relogin, the achievements will be gone. (Leaderboards work perfectly though)

iOS 6.1.3, Unity 3D and Prime31 Google Play Game Services Plugin

Completely clueless what could cause that. I also unlocked heaps on my android on the same google account. So when logging in on iOS it should show these achievements, too, it doesn't.

```
2013-07-24 10:10:53.734 xxx[3669/0x3bfd1b88] [lvl=2] __49-[GPGManager executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_0() GAMES RESPONSE (games.achievementDefinitions.list) =
{
    items =     (
                {
            achievementType = STANDARD;
            description = "Survive 20 seconds";
            id = xxx;
            initialState = REVEALED;
            isRevealedIconUrlDefault = 0;
            isUnlockedIconUrlDefault = 0;
            kind = "games#achievementDefinition";
            name = Beginner;
            revealedIconUrl = "https://lh6.ggpht.com/w8UAkuhdsVJ7WsYPpqAUnTKy88k8rN8njKcGj5hu8A8Xa-xxx=fbw=1";
            unlockedIconUrl = "https://lh6.ggpht.com/w8UAkuhdsVJ7WsYPpqAUnTKy88k8rN8njKcGj5hu8A8Xa-xxx";
        },


2013-07-24 10:14:50.279 xxx[3669/0x3bfd1b88] [lvl=2] -[GPGManager executeOperation:completionHandler:] GAMES REQUEST (games.achievements.unlock) =
{
    achievementId = xxx;
}

2013-07-24 10:14:51.459 xxx[3669/0x3bfd1b88] [lvl=2] __49-[GPGManager executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_0() Service Operation Succeeded [games.achievements.unlock]

2013-07-24 10:14:51.459 xxx[3669/0x3bfd1b88] [lvl=2] __49-[GPGManager executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_0() GAMES RESPONSE (games.achievements.unlock) =
{
    kind = "games#achievementUnlockResponse";
    newlyUnlocked = 0;
}
```

Comment: If I init the Prime31 like this all is good, phew:
PlayGameServices.init( "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", false, false, true );

Comment: Hey Garry, I'm having the same issue. However, I'm using PlayGameServices.framework (Google's own implementation) which doesn't appear to have an option to not load the achievement data while signing in (the second "false" in your init call. Did you find out anything that could help me here? Thanks!